# Probablity of two randomly selected socks are different color?

Tags: probability, statistics

A drawer contains 5 blue socks and 5 white socks.  Two socks are randomly selected from the drawer.

**Q: What is the probably that the two socks are different color?**

Is finding this probably the same as finding the probability that the 2 socks are the same color? I was able to find that probability but had a hard time finding it:

- $S_1$: White sock  $S_1^C$: Blue
- $S_2$: white sock  $S_2^C$: Blue

$P(S_2\mid S_1)\cdot P(S_1)+P(S_2^C\mid S_1^C)\cdot P(S_1^C) = 
(4/9)\cdot (1/2)+(4/9)\cdot (1/2)= 4/9$

Comment: The first sock can be of either color.  Then there are $5$ socks left (of the $9$ total), which don't match the first one, hence $\frac 59$.  This plus the probability that they match in color must add to $1$, as the events are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.

Comment: When you pick one sock, there are more socks of the other colour left, so the chance of picking a different colour must be greater than ${1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the socks are the same color is: $P(S_2\mid S_1)\cdot P(S_1)+P(S_2^C\mid S_1^C)\cdot P(S_1^C)\\ = 
(4/9)\cdot (1/2)+(5/9)\cdot (1/2) \\ = 4/9$

The probability that the socks are different colors is: $P(S_2^C\mid S_1)\cdot P(S_1)+P(S_2\mid S_1^C)\cdot P(S_1^C)\\ = 
(5/9)\cdot (1/2)+(5/9)\cdot (1/2) \\ = 5/9$

Answer (score 4):

From 10 socks you are choosing 2, so you have $\binom{10}{2}$ possibilities. And to two socks to be different color you have to pick one blue and one white so you have $\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{1}$ possibilities. So the final result is $\frac{25}{45}=\frac{5}{9}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I do not know the route you used.